# Erro NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

Quando tento abrir o programa ele não encontra a classe do nativehook, mas ele está no classpath

Erro:

```
C:\Users\Paulo\Desktop>java -jar AutoClick.jar
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jnativehook/keyboard/NativeKeyListener
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
            ... 6 more

C:\Users\Paulo\Desktop>pause
Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
```

.classpath

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7">
        <accessrules>
            <accessrule kind="nonaccessible" pattern="&quot;sun/**&quot;"/>
        </accessrules>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/JNativeHook.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.pauloabr.AutoClicker.AutoClicker
```

Eu preciso colocar algo á mais no `manifest.mf`?

Esse erro aparece quando executo no cmd, quando executo direto no jar aparece "java exception has ocurred."

Comment: Sim, e ele está dentro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mais detalhes neste link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar

Basicamente, não há forma oficial de se carregar as classes de um JAR que está dentro de outro JAR. Existe uma RFE (*request for enhancement*) bem antiga (desde 2002) sobre isso, mas nunca saiu do lugar: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4648386

Dito isso, você precisará de algum outro tipo de solução que envolva ou "explodir" o JAR interno dentro do JAR externo, colocando então tudo diretamente no JAR externo, ou então obter um `ClassLoader` especializado ou escrever o seu próprio.

Caso opte por usar um `ClassLoader` especializado, dentre as sugestões levantadas na pergunta do StackOverflow em inglês linkada no começo desta resposta, temos o [JarClassLoader](http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php) e o [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de:

```
java -jar AutoClick.jar
```

Tente:

```
java -cp ./libs/JNativeHook.jar -jar AutoClick.jar
```

Comment: Isso funciona, mas só se eu abro pelo cmd, quero abrir direto pelo .jar

Answer (score 0):

Adicione ao seu `manifest.mf` a seguinte linha:

```
Class-Path: libs/JNativeHook.jar
```

Talvez, o seguinte também possa funcionar para carregar um JAR dentro do outro, dependendo de como ele está organizado internamente:

```
Class-Path: ./JNativeHook.jar
```

Ou então:

```
Class-Path: ./libs/JNativeHook.jar
```

Comment: Ele até funciona, mas só se tiver a pasta libs/JNativehook.jar no mesmo nivel do .jar, não tem como pegar o que está dentro do libs do .jar?

Comment: @pauloabr Editado. Veja se agora dá certo.

Comment: não funcionou :/