# Jar não executa

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

Estou usando o netbeans e maven. Quando tento executar o arquivo jar no cmd, o erro apresentado é "nenhum atributo de manifesto principal em".

Segue o código do nbactions.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
        <action>
            <actionName>run</actionName>
            <packagings>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </packagings>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-classes</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <exec.args>-classpath %classpath br.com.swing.Main</exec.args>
                <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
                <exec.workingdir>C:\Users\Fabio\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EnterpretadorQRcode\src\main\java\br\com\swing</exec.workingdir>
            </properties>
        </action>
        <action>
            <actionName>debug</actionName>
            <packagings>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </packagings>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-classes</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <exec.args>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -classpath %classpath br.com.swing.Main</exec.args>
                <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
                <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
                <exec.workingdir>C:\Users\Fabio\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EnterpretadorQRcode\src\main\java\br\com\swing</exec.workingdir>
            </properties>
        </action>
        <action>
            <actionName>profile</actionName>
            <packagings>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
            </packagings>
            <goals>
                <goal>process-classes</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <exec.args>-classpath %classpath br.com.swing.Main</exec.args>
                <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
                <exec.workingdir>C:\Users\Fabio\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EnterpretadorQRcode\src\main\java\br\com\swing</exec.workingdir>
            </properties>
        </action>
    </actions>
```

````
segue codigo do pom.xml

``` lang-xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Enterpretador</groupId>
    <artifactId>EnterpretadorQRcode</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.1stleg</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnativehook</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>EnterpretadorQRcode</name>
</project>
````

Comment: Você poderia editar a pergunta e colocar o seu `pom.xml`?

Comment: Consegui colocar

Answer (score 1):

É necessário adicionar a classe principal no arquivo `pom.xml`. Procure a tag plugins e adicione o seguinte:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <archive>
               <manifest>
                  <mainClass>br.com.renan.MinhaClasse</mainClass>
               </manifest>
            </archive>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Adicionei essas informações do plugin no pom.xml. começou apresentar esse erro: 
Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for Enterpretador:EnterpretadorQRcode:jar:1.0
'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 23, column 20

It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.

Comment: @FabioDaSilvaGarcia acho que está faltando a versão, adicionei a tag version na resposta

Comment: Acrescentei a seguinte linha: 
<version>3.1.1</version> 
o erro mudou agora esta informando que não esta encontrando as classes da dependência do jnativehook

Comment: @FabioDaSilvaGarcia qual é a mensagem?

Comment: Segue link do print screen [link](https://ibb.co/PQ6Mq5n)

Comment: No Netbeans tente um clean e build

Comment: Continua a mesma coisa. o Arquivo jar esta com 13KB e muito pequeno para estar com as dependências

Comment: Olhe [isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52816/erro-noclassdeffounderror/52863), talvez possa ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema acrescentando um plugin de compilação nao sei como funciona direito. Mas dessa forma ele cria dois jars. Um com as classes sem as dependências e outro com as dependências. Segue linhas acrescentadas no pom:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>  
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>br.com.swing.Main</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```